# Change screen resolution while in safe mode for normal mode

Tags: windows-7, resolution, safe-mode, normal-mode

A screen of mine burnt out, and was replaced with a screen of lower resolution. It works in safe mode as that is in 800x600 resolution, but when I try to boot to normal mode, it fails. Is there a way to change the resolution for normal mode in safe mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you're in Safe Mode, try setting the resolution to 800x600. That should persist once you boot into normal mode.

Comment: Warning: This might not work in Windows 8.

Comment: Not working in Windows 10

Answer (score 5):

If all else fails, uninstall the graphics card from the "Device Manager" while in safe-mode, and restart in normal mode. Then install the drivers again.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this exact thing happen to me (in my case I have a game that occasionally hoses my desktop resolution which shall go nameless but whose initials are SWTOR).

The problem is that I'm running under Windows 8. On my system at least, the accepted answer no longer works. You can change the resolution under safe mode, but rather than changing your desktop resolution, it will instead change the resolution you get next time you boot into safe mode (a change that seems not only unhelpful, but actively dangerous).

I also tried uninstalling the monitor driver, and that didn't help. I didn't try the video card. I'll try that next time.

The least destructive solution I've found is to **restore the system from a recent restore point**. I had one from the day before, but even if it had been weeks, that would be better than the previous solution I used (reinstalling Windows).