# Revert resolution change in Windows 7 (screen gone black after change)

Tags: windows-7, resolution

I changed my screen resolution from `800x600` to `1280x1074` and now Windows starts up but there is no display and a message comes on a black screen saying `Input not supported`. I can only start Windows in safe mode.

I checked in safe mode but there was no restore point available. I am using Windows 7.  How can I get my screen resolution back?

**EDIT:**
i tried  setting the resolution to 800x600 in safe mode and rebooting but still the screen remains black.
Also i enabled the `600x480` mode but still the same.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/303443/change-screen-resolution-while-in-safe-mode-for-normal-mode

Comment: You're enabling it [from the Boot options screen](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2283329#2283329) **not** from within the desktop. Boot into the desktop, change the resolution. Even if it's set to 800x600, reset it & boot back to normal mode.

Comment: @Sathya i have done exactly what you have mentioned. Logged into safe mode, changed the resolution to `800x600` and rebooted into normal mode. but still the black screen appears

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the registry keys that holds the resolution information for the display:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Hardware Profiles\UnitedVideo\CONTROL\VIDEO`
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Hardware Profiles\UnitedVideo\CONTROL\VIDEO`

Each of these branches contains several keys relating to the resolution:

`DefaultSettings.XResolution`
`DefaultSettings.YResolution`

Reboot into safe mode.
Export the whole branch to make a backup incase something goes wrong.
Find all the keys with the resolution that is not working, and set them to the resolution that worked.
Reboot.

Comment: I see now this question is ancient, hopefully this will help someone else with the same issue. This fix can also be done through remote registry if enabled

Answer (score 2):

You should be using VGA mode, not Safe mode.

- **Safe mode:** Your system is bootstrapped using the generic VGA device driver, `vga.sys`, which of course doesn't know how to take advantage of whatever non-VGA capabilities your display adapter has in the first place.
- **VGA mode:** Your system is bootstrapped using the proper, installed, device driver for your display adapter, but with the display mode forced to a VGA 640×480 8-bit colour mode.

Changing the display resolution used by `vga.sys` does not change the display resolution used by your *actual* display device driver.  Display resolutions are (of course) per-adapter things, and an adapter driven by the generic VGA driver is not necessarily considered the same as an adapter driven by its proper device driver.  Their settings are saved under different names.

Bring up your system in VGA mode, *without* Safe mode, and then, from the Windows Explorer Control Panel, re-set the display resolution as desired.

Comment: i selected VGA mode in the boot menu but then also the black screen appeared. Finally i got a different size monitor by my friend and then the display became ok and then i decreased the resolution and then changed the monitor again.

Comment: Sometimes the VGA mode doesn't work - which can be a complete pain - and even uninstalling/reinstalling the drivers revives the problem. In these situations (if you've got RDP enabled or VNC) you can remote in and change the resolution - can be a bit problematic but most times it works for us.