# Change screen resolution in safe mode to the one in normal mode

Tags: windows-7, resolution, intel-graphics, safe-mode

I have used [this](https://superuser.com/questions/303443/change-screen-resolution-while-in-safe-mode-for-normal-mode) link, but have not found it useful, but anyways

I have a windows 7 64bit laptop, Intel Core 2 CPU processor and I a using safe mode. The default resolution is 800 X 600 so I changed it to 1024 X 768. This looks similar to the one in normal mode, but is *a bit* stretched. I want it **exactly** the same, as apps like bluestacks and windows live movie maker fail to open due to the graphics not the right size, or due to *driver problems* . Please can you help me get exactly the same resolution?

Thanks,
cybergodfather666

Comment: The first sentence of your question makes no sense. Please consider rewording and rephrasing your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Safe Mode does loads only default graphics drivers and not drivers specific to your GPU. This means that most media will fail to play or will not play well.

Even if you were able to get the resolution to be the same as "normal mode" Bluestacks, Windows Movie Maker, and other applications that attempt to use the GPUs capabilities will fail in Safe Mode for this reason.

The deeper question you need to resolve is this: Why are you running in Safe Mode?

Comment: I am running in safe mode because it takes ages to boot into normal mode and the CPU usage is mostly 0%. When I fix this, it causes BSODs.

But @music2myear is it possible to edit the registry/anything to load more drivers? And if so how?

Comment: Nope. The entire point of Safe Mode is for diagnosis and repair. It is designed NOT to load this extra junk because that junk is likely to be causing problems. That's why it's called "Safe Mode". It's not called "Use Me Instead" mode for a reason. You can create a new hardware profile and set up a different set of loading parameters that way, but that's complicated. Fix the problems with your normal mode to make this work.

Comment: Reinstall windows and it will boot quick again. Also, keep in mind that bluestacks is very resource heavy. It has services to run in the background and in safe-mode they simply don't start when windows starts. As a result, BlueStacks starts slower in safe-mode or doesn't work correctly at all. This can be adjusted to work the same in normal mode too. The idea is that BlueStacks is always running so your apps and stuff get updated even when you are not using BlueStacks. I really dislike this method, so when I used it, that was the first behavior I stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this question was downvoted. Anyway, the answer to your question: it's impossible.

The point of safe mode is to load a minimum set of drivers. Usually the default safe mode graphics driver is some old-school variant of 640x480 VGA resolution. I'm surprised you were able to get 1024x768 resolution out of safe mode.

Finally, there's no way you can go from 800x600 to 1024x768 and change the aspect ratios because both of them are 4:3 display modes.

Safe mode drivers are minimalistic and I wouldn't expect one to allow you to change aspect ratios.